# how to select first two rows from a group

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi We have 3 Table of a music which is something like this in `MySql` :

**1st Table :**

the first table is for `playlist` table where music playlist is exist.

```
playlistId           playlistTitle          categoryId

1                    hello                  0
2                    wow                    0
3                    wi-fi                  0
4                    awesome                0
5                    sixer                  1
6                    four                   1
7                    boundary               2
```

**2nd Table :**

2nd table is for `songRelation` table where every playlist is associated with thier song

```
playlistId            songId

1                     4
1                     3
1                     43
1                     57
1                     98
2                     56
2                     67
2                     90
2                     78
3                     98
3                     78
3                     89
43                    90
```

**3rd Table :**
the 3rd table is for `song` table where song detail exist

```
songId                songTitle

4                     hello
3                     real hero
43                    singalone
57                    awesom
98                    really
78                    sakaka
98                    shikwa
89                    moha
90                    hello2
67                    Sneh
```

actually i want to get result something like this :

```
playlistId  songId    categoryId songTitle

1           4         0          hello
1           3         0          real hero
2           56        0          singalone
2           67        0          Sneh
3           78        0          sakaka
3           98        0          Shikwa
```

where the every `playlistId` will be with their first `2` `songId` and with their `categoryId`and also with `songTitle`.

Comment: @vkp limit will not work because, limit will limits the total found results..not the only two which i want with every `playlistId`

Comment: Minor typo: song id 98 appears twice

Comment: Also, how are you ordering 'first 2 songid'? Are they ordered by id in ascending order? That's not the case with 3, as you select '98' and then '78'.

Comment: @McAdam331 Plz Check the updated questions. actually we want in assending order.

Comment: I understand now. I was able to make an answer, thanks for clearing it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to determine a concrete order for your first two rows. The order they appear visually should be irrelevant in a properly normalized database.

For this example, let's say you want to find the 'two lowest songIds in each playlist'. This is a [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) problem, and there are many other questions on that tag.

You can do that using the following query:

```
SELECT s.playlistId, s.songId
FROM songRelation s
WHERE(
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM songRelation s2
  WHERE s.playlistId = s2.playlistId AND s.songId >= s2.songId) <= 2;
```

The 2 at the end represents the number of rows per group you want (2 songs per playlist) and the condition inside the subquery pulls the two smallest songIds. If you wanted the two largest, just change it to `s.songId <= s2.songId`. Now, to get the category information, you just join in the playlist table:

```
SELECT p.id, t.songId, p.categoryId
FROM playlist p
JOIN(
  SELECT s.playlistId, s.songId
  FROM songRelation s
  WHERE(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM songRelation s2
    WHERE s.playlistId = s2.playlistId AND s.songId >= s2.songId) <= 2) t ON t.playlistId = p.id;
```

Note that with this specific sample data, there is no playlist 43 in the table so it won't be returned by my results.

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/79343/4) example.

Comment: Can you tell me how can i get also `songTitle` in the Result.

Comment: Plz Review Updated result table